# How to wakeup lazyloading on <details> expanding?

Tags: jquery, html, lazy-loading

I use Lazy Load plugin from jquery.com https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/

Everything works great, but i got some `<details>` tags on page, with images and...

When i click on `detail` tag i got:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OizhP.jpg

And i have to scroll at least  1 px to images start lazyloading.

Is there any way to wakeup lazyloading on expanding(click) `<detail>` tag?

I appreciate any help, btw. im beginner

Greetings.

Comment: `$('details').on('toggle', function(){$(window).trigger('scroll');});`